# Geometric sequence and series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hello i need help please,
$$
\begin{cases}
u_0&= 1\\                               
u_{n+1}&=\frac{3u_n + 2v_n}{5}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
    v_0 = 2\\
v_{n+1} = \frac{2u_n+3v_n}{5}
\end{cases}
$$

**1.**  Calculate $u_1$, $u_2$, $v_1$, and $v_2$.

**2.**  We consider the sequence $(d_n)$ defined for any natural number $n$ by $d_n = v_n-u_n$.

**a.**  Show that the sequence $(d_n)$ is a geometric sequence of which we will give its common ratio and its first term.

**b.**  Deduce the expression of $d_n$ depending on $n$.

**3.**  We consider the sequence *(s_n)* defined for any natural number $n$ by $s_n = u_n+v_n$.

**a.**  Calculate $s_0$, $s_1$, and $s_2$.  What can we guess?

**b.**  Show that, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $s_{n+1} = s_n$.  What can we deduce? Deduce an expression of $u_n$ and $v_n$ depending on $n$.

**5.**  Determine depending on $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

**a.**  $T_n = u_0 + u_1 + \dots + u_n$.

**b.**  $W_n = v_0 + v_1 + \dots + v_n$.

Actually i answered the first question and the second, and i found the common ratio is $1/5$ and the first term 1 so $d_n = 1 \cdot 1/5^n$
For the 3. I found $3$
And i cant resolve the 4 and 5  can you help me

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

*Hints.* Since you have successfully found $d_n=v_n-u_n$ and $s_n=v_n+u_n$ as functions of $n,$ then you can find expressions for $u_n$ and $v_n$ simply by subtraction and addition of the above equations, so that you have that $$2v_n=s_n+d_n$$ and $$2u_n=s_n-d_n.$$

From here it should be easy to continue.

Comment: But dn is dn= vn- un and can just olease show me the first step because i don’t really understand how to do it

Comment: @Dan I have accordingly corrected.

Comment: So i calculated un = 1.4 and vn = 1.6 ?

Comment: @Dan If your computations were correct then those are constant sequences, which you should be able to solve to finish off the problem

Comment: im sorry but i didnt get it, how can i find their expression please

Comment: @Dan Do you know how to solve simultaneous linear equations?

Comment: I don’t know how to do